# I don't know what is happening in the given code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class pyt():

    print(4)

pyt()
pyt()
```

is giving only one output 4. I think it should print two fours but since my intuition is not correct. I wanted to know why this program is printing only one 4.

Comment: Class level code is run only once at class initialization. You might want to have a constructor (`__init__`) to run code for every instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-is-the-purpose-of-class-methods)

Comment: @NelsonGon no, this is nothing to do with class methods in Python. OP is either expecting code in the class body to be re-run for each instantiation, or perhaps has `class` confused with `def`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes I will retract.I just thought that post would help them to understand the difference between classes and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the program only prints `4` once is because, the `print()` function is only called when you define the class:

```
class pyt():
    print(4)
```

Output:

```
4
```

When you call the class, the `print()` function won't initiate:

```
class pyt():
    print(4)

pyt()
pyt()
pyt()
pyt()
pyt()
pyt()
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to use `def` instead of a `class`

```
def pyt():

    print(4)

pyt()
pyt()
```

The output will be:

[image]

You can read more on a difference between `def` and `class` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867494/differences-between-class-and-def)

If you want to do it with the `class` keyword

```
class pyt():
    def __init__(self, value_to_print=4):
        self.value_to_print = value_to_print
        
    def print_value(self):
        print(self.value_to_print)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyt_obj = pyt()
    pyt_obj.print_value()
    pyt_obj.print_value()
```

The output will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a `function` instead of a `class` if you want to be able to call your code out twice then you should do this instead:

```
    def pyt():
        print(4)
    pyt()
    pyt()
```

The result will be:

```
    4
    4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with a class,like:

```
class pyt():
    def __init__(self):
        print(1)

pyt()
```

You could get [more information here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/) about `__init__`.